# Where is GNUCash in 20.04 LTS?

Tags: gnucash

I have just installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a Lenovo laptop.

I am keen to install GNUCash stable v4. At the GNUCash site, the message is that Ubuntu has that stable version in the local Ubuntu Software repository.

However, the search function doesn't find it.

The latest version 4.4 was released late December 2020. Does that mean v4.4 is not yet available in the local repository?

If so, is an earlier version available?

If so, how can I access and install it, please?

Comment: Version 4.4 is for Windows and Mac, right now. The Ubuntu repos have 3.10. Make sure you have all the repos enabled except proposed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. I am still exploring but so far have only used the graphical interface tool called Ubuntu Software. I will check the enabled repos and see what I can find from a terminal.

Comment: Success. GNUCash installed. Thanks for the advice on enabling all repos.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status update - my version is 3.8, rather than 4.4 or 3.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

GNUCash version 4.4 is for Windows and Mac, right now. The Ubuntu repos have 3.10. Make sure you have all the repos enabled except "proposed".

Success... GNUCash is now installed.

Comment: I successfully installed be.8 rather than 3.10 or v4.4.  Sufficient for me to get started, thank you.

Comment: @JohnAngelico I don't understand what be.8 means. Also, if my comments, and my answer, were helpful, please remember to accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Argh autocorrect. That should read v3.8

Comment: @JohnAngelico Why 3.8 and not 3.10, which is in the Ubuntu repos?

Comment: I installed from the Software Centre (the equivalent of sudo apt install) and that is what I saw on the splash screen at startup.
Here is the help-about detail:
Version: 3.8
Build ID: 3.8b+(2019-12-29)
Finance::Quote: 1.49

Comment: @JohnAngelico Ah yes... in 20.04 3.8 is current. In 20.10 it's 3.10. In 21.04 it'll be 4.4. Cheers!